# Change build name from android project using cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I developed a mobile app using cordova and i'm having a little problem with the Android project when i build the project.
When i install the app on my phone it appears the correct name, but the build name is always CordovaApp.apk.

Exp:

PhoneName: MyApp

Build: CordovaApp.apk

I have tried to change the project name on the the build.xml file, but it is chnage again on the build.

```
<project name="MyApp" default="help">
```

IS there a way to change the build name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change it in project configuration file (/www/config.xml) not in build file.

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova team have hardcoded in the 'CordovaApp' name because of potential issues with unusual unicode characters in app names. For English-language apps, this is usually not a problem, but Cordova is an international project and strange characters can cause issues.

http://www.cordovacircus.com/articles/cordova-android-name